# StateFlow collect emit NullPointerException

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

My repository layer have a `MutableStateFlow`, collecting it in my ViewModel. I am getting this NPE on some user devices

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at a.b.c.ui.viewmodel.HomeViewModel$collectFlowState$$inlined$collect$1.emit(HomeViewModel.java:189)
       at a.b.c.ui.viewmodel.HomeViewModel$collectFlowState$$inlined$collect$1$1.invokeSuspend(HomeViewModel.java:12)
       at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(BaseContinuationImpl.java:33)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.resume(DispatchedTaskKt.java:176)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTaskKt.dispatch(DispatchedTaskKt.java:111)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.dispatchResume(CancellableContinuationImpl.java:308)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeImpl(CancellableContinuationImpl.java:318)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.CancellableContinuationImpl.resumeUndispatched(CancellableContinuationImpl.java:400)
       at kotlinx.coroutines.android.HandlerContext$scheduleResumeAfterDelay$$inlined$Runnable$1.run(HandlerContext.java:19)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7830)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1040)
```

`MutableStateFlow` is of non-null data, if the data is somehow null the app would have crashed earlier.

An example how I am using `StateFlow` on the repository (producer) layer:

```
data class ApiData(...)
private val INITIAL = ApiData(...)
private var someState = INITIAL

private val dataSF = MutableStateFlow(someState)

fun dataFlow() = dataSF

// called on remote api success, we poll for updated data (delta) from the server
fun onDataChangeAvailable(x: Int, y: Double) {
        someState = someState.copy(x = x, y= y)
        dataSF.value = someState
}
```

The ViewModel (consumer) side:

```
private val repository // constructor injected; repository is Application scoped
private val job = SupervisorJob()
private val uiScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main + job)
// Viewmodel init block
init {
     uiScope.launch {
                repository.dataFlow().collect { // crash sometimes here.
                    // consume values
                }
        }
}

override fun onCleared() {
        job.cancel()
        super.onCleared()
    }
```

From the [StateFlow doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-state-flow/index.html)

> State flow never completes. A call to Flow.collect on a state flow never completes normally, and neither does a coroutine started by the Flow.launchIn function.

and the [Flow doc](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-flow/index.html) recommends to catch exceptions like this

```
try {
    flow.collect { value ->
        println("Received $value")
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println("The flow has thrown an exception: $e")
}
```

So is it recommended to swallow all exceptions from the `collect` of a `StateFlow` or only those thrown by the producer end? What is the cause of the NPE in general?

Comment: Could you please show us your `MutableStateFlow` implementation emitting the values.

Comment: Hi @ChristianB have made some changes. Kindly take another look. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us your HomeViewModel too?

Comment: Added @hamid Thanks!

Comment: What is this dataFlow() method in the init{} of viewModel? it appears it's not in the repository, since you've set dataSF to private..

Comment: The stacktrace looks more like the issue is inside the `collect {...}` block in your `HomeViewModel`. Could you post more details on whats happening there?

Comment: `dataFlow()` exposes the private `dataSF` @USMAN

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu i tried exact same basic scenario with null checks and non null checks and even i used editText and button clickListener by constantly  sending values with rotating device i'm not having this issue. and im also receiving value i init of viewModel and sending value from activity.
by the way what is your kotlin version? im on ``1.4.10``

Comment: kotlin version is `1.4.20`, I used to get the same error but with KNPE in `1.3.72` before they were unified in `1.4.x`

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem but it was happening when recreates the fragment because **Stateflow** still has an old value so simply add a check before call `flow.collect`, check for flow contains init value something like this

```
if (viewModel.mutableStateFlow.value == YourInitValue) {
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.mutableStateFlow.timeLineData.collect {
        
            }
        }
    }
```

because if stateflow didn't contain init value that means collect method called before

Answer (score 1):

"If we just call cancel, it doesn’t mean that the coroutine work will just stop."

I resolve this problem checking if the coroutine is active using `ensureActive()`

```kotlin
...
       job = uiScope.launch {
                ensureActive()
                repository.dataFlow().collect { // crash sometimes here.
                    // consume values
                }
        }

override fun onCleared() {
        job.cancel()
        super.onCleared()
    }
```

You can see detail of this solutin in
[How to cancel collect coroutine StateFlow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68548595/how-to-cancel-collect-coroutine-stateflow)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. Actually I was mapping the StateFlow to something else and collecting that.
In the mapping process I was using `!!` notation!
Removing that notation solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could solve your problem

```
private val dataSF = MutableStateFlow<Int?>(someState)
```

Comment: My Flow always has some value. Don't wan't to introduce un-necessary nullable values.

Comment: I think this is not a device issue, is there any specific scenario to reproduce the crash?